# hibernate criteria query - property of sub-property

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am using spring MVC 3.0 with the jqgrid plugin. I am building the search feature for the jqgrid which sends a json object accross to the server side. I created a dummy java class to parse the json for the jqgrid whenever the search is triggered. All is well up to this point.

I am dynamically creating my criteria query as the user is free to choose the search criteria (equal, no equal,... etc). Here is an example of the json string sent by the jqgrid.

```
{
    "groupOp": "AND",
    "rules": [{
        "field": "company",
        "op": "cn",
        "data": "School"},
    {
        "field": "numberOfStudents",
        "op": "eq",
        "data": "2"}]
}​
```

This is the Java class used as a template to parse this JSON:

```
public class JsonJqgridSearchModel {

    public String groupOp;

    public ArrayList<JqgridSearchCriteria> rules;
}
```

Notice the type called JqgridSearchCriteria. This is a class which simply returns one restriction any time I call its `getRestriction()` method. Here is the `JqgridSearchCriteria` class:

```
public class JqgridSearchCriteria {

    public String field;

    public String op;

    public String data;

    public SimpleExpression getRestriction(){
        if(op.equals("cn")){
            return Restrictions.like(field, data, MatchMode.ANYWHERE);
        }else if(op.equals("eq")){
            return Restrictions.eq(field, data);
        }else if(op.equals("ne")){
            return Restrictions.ne(field, data);
        }else if(op.equals("lt")){
            return Restrictions.lt(field, data);
        }else if(op.equals("le")){
            return Restrictions.le(field, data);
        }else if(op.equals("gt")){
            return Restrictions.gt(field, data);
        }else if(op.equals("ge")){
            return Restrictions.ge(field, data);
        }else{
            return null;
        }       
    }   
}
```

If you observe the JSON string, you will see why the **field** and **data** are used to return the SimpleExpression via the getRestriction().

Here is the thing: I have **Object-A** which has **Object-B** as a reference. What I am getting from the grid is **Object-B.getName()** thus there is a `JqgridSearchCriteria` where the **field=Object-B.getName()** and the data is the name supplied by the user. When this runs I get an exception as follows:

```
Internal Error
Sorry, we encountered an internal error.
Details
could not get a field value by reflection getter of tt.edu.sbcs.model.Organization.id
org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:62)
org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:230)
org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3852)
org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3560)
org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:204)
org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:243)
org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:449)
org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.nullSafeSet(ManyToOneType.java:142)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindPositionalParameters(Loader.java:1789)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindParameterValues(Loader.java:1760)
                               .
                               .
                               .**
```

Here is a snippet of where it all comes together.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(CorporateRegistration.class); 
Iterator<JqgridSearchCriteria> iterator = jsonJqgridSearchModel.rules.iterator();
String operation = jsonJqgridSearchModel.groupOp;
if(operation.equals("AND")){
    Conjunction conjunction = Restrictions.conjunction();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){  
        conjunction.add(iterator.next().getRestriction());
    }           
    criteria.add(conjunction);
}//conjunctions are for AND operation
else{
    Disjunction disjunction = Restrictions.disjunction();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){  
        disjunction.add(iterator.next().getRestriction());
    }           
    criteria.add(disjunction);          
}//disjunctions are for OR operations       
    for(Object o: criteria.list()){
        corpRegList.add((CorporateRegistration)o);
    }
```

I also tried searching for numbers, but the value coming across is a string. 
Do I use the createAlias of the criteria?
Can I specify the datatype of the property called data when I return the SimpleExpression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who may be looking for the answer, I used a sub criteria. That is if you have a criteria called **A**, for these types of situations you can say `A.createCriteria(field).add(conjunction);`
where field refers to the actual property in the owning entity. Here is something I created to allow for a more generic search logic that is project specific. So when you call `A.list()` you are good to go. Its a bit long but quite simple to understand.

```
public class JqgridSearchCriteria {

    public String field;

    public String op;

    public String data;

    public String dataType;

    public String dataProperty;

    public SimpleExpression getSimpleExpression(String myField, Object o){
        if(op.equals("cn")){
            return Restrictions.like(myField, o.toString(), MatchMode.ANYWHERE);
        }else if(op.equals("eq")){
            return Restrictions.eq(myField, o);
        }else if(op.equals("ne")){
            return Restrictions.ne(myField, o);
        }else if(op.equals("lt")){
            return Restrictions.lt(myField, o);
        }else if(op.equals("le")){
            return Restrictions.le(myField, o);
        }else if(op.equals("gt")){
            return Restrictions.gt(myField, o);
        }else if(op.equals("ge")){
            return Restrictions.ge(myField, o);
        }else{
            return null;
        }       
    }   

    public void addMyRestriction(String groupOperation, Criteria criteria){
        Conjunction conjunction = Restrictions.conjunction();
        Disjunction disjunction = Restrictions.disjunction();
        if(groupOperation.equals("AND")){
            if(dataType.isEmpty()){
                conjunction.add(this.getSimpleExpression(field, data));
                criteria.add(conjunction);
            }else{
                if(dataType.equals("Calendar")){
                    try{
                        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy");
                        Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(data);
                        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                        cal.setTime(date);
                        conjunction.add(this.getSimpleExpression(field, cal));
                        criteria.add(conjunction);
                    }catch (ParseException e){
                        System.out.println("Exception :"+e);
                    }                   //used for calendar data types 
                }else if(dataType.equals("Long")){
                    Long myLong = Long.parseLong(data);
                    conjunction.add(this.getSimpleExpression(field, myLong));
                    criteria.add(conjunction);
                                        //used for Long data types
                }else if(dataType.equals("Integer")){
                    Integer myInt = Integer.parseInt(data);
                    conjunction.add(this.getSimpleExpression(field, myInt));
                    criteria.add(conjunction);
                                        //used for Integer data types
                }else{
                    conjunction.add(this.getSimpleExpression(dataProperty, data));
                    criteria.createCriteria(field).add(conjunction);
                }                       //used for custom or project specific data types
            }// AND operation used conjunctions
        }else{
            if(dataType.isEmpty()){
                disjunction.add(this.getSimpleExpression(field, data));
                criteria.add(disjunction);
            }else{

                if(dataType.equals("Calendar")){
                    try{
                        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy");
                        Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(data);
                        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                        cal.setTime(date);
                        disjunction.add(this.getSimpleExpression(field, cal));
                        criteria.add(disjunction);
                    }catch (ParseException e){
                        System.out.println("Exception :"+e);
                    } 
                }else if(dataType.equals("Long")){
                    Long myLong = Long.parseLong(data);
                    disjunction.add(this.getSimpleExpression(field, myLong));
                    criteria.add(disjunction);
                }else if(dataType.equals("Integer")){
                    Integer myInt = Integer.parseInt(data);
                    disjunction.add(this.getSimpleExpression(field, myInt));
                    criteria.add(disjunction);
                }else{
                    disjunction.add(this.getSimpleExpression(dataProperty, data));
                    criteria.createCriteria(field).add(disjunction);
                }
            }           
        }// OR operation used disjunctions
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With regard to the searching for numbers I think you will need a "type" property on your JqgridSearchCriteria class. Also in the UI you will probably want to tailor the available operators so that the user cannot select "Contains" for numeric values, for example.

In a similar system we just developed we used ['string', 'number', 'date'] for the search value types. Every column the user can select for searching has a type so that we can use javascript to present an appropriate list of operators.

This will mean that you will know to cast the search criteria value properly when constructing the Criteria. It adds complexity to your application but I don't see any alternative.